# Styling checkbox using CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to style a custom checkbox on a form; my HTML looks something like this:

```
<form id="contact">
  <input type="checkbox" id="option1" />
  <label for="option1">Option</label>
</form>
```

My CSS looks something like this:

```
form input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
form label {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
form label:before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I wanted to add a background color when the checkbox is ticked so I added this rule:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Which works like I wanted to, but I need to be specific only for the rule to work on a contact form, so I changed it to:

```
#contact input[type="checkbox"]:checked + #contact label:before {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

This time it does not work. The background does not change when the checkbox is ticked.

My question is what is wrong with the CSS? What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a checkbox using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. The selector should be:

```
#contact input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

The reason it wasn't working was because `#contact` isn't an adjacent sibling with the `input[type="checkbox"]` element. You need to omit the second `#contact` id selector.

In other words, the selector:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + #contact label {}
```

Would attempt to select the following `label` element:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="option1" />
<div id="#contact">
   <label for="option1">Option</label>
</div>
```

Since the `input` checkbox element doesn't have an adjacent `#contact` element, nothing was being selected.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, mate! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
form input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; opacity: 0; }

form label {
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative; }

form  label:before {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000; }
    
    #contact input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before { background-color: #ccc; }
```

```html
<form id="contact">
       <input type="checkbox" id="option1" />
       <label for="option1">Option</label>
   </form>
```

Please just update this code `#contact input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before { background-color: #ccc; }`

Comment: How is this different from what I posted 3 hours ago?

Comment: you did wrong here http://prntscr.com/9sdt1i
you already specified right selector already so remove beore + label selector